# cpp exe file working on wsl but not working on windows10 cmd

Tags: c++, gcc, build, g++, exe

I make an executable file with g++ in WSL with the command `g++ main.cpp foo.cpp` and is working fine in WSL environment.

But, In windows 10, command line, when I try to execute the file, it says *The program cannot start or run due to incompatibility with 64-bit versions of Windows.* [Unsupported 16-Bit Application]

**So, the question is** "How can I build a 64 or 32-bit executable file with g++ in WSL."
Currently, I guess I am getting the 16-Bit Version.

Comment: Please ask me in case you need some more information. Thanks!

Comment: According to this [page](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/gccg-compilers-default-64-bit-compile-mode-sles-11) , it says the gcc and g++ compilers default to 64-bit mode compilation. But why am I getting the 16-bit version?

Comment: How can I make sure that g++ will build 32 or 64 bit files? I am finding over the net and cannot find the solution yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WSL is a Linux layer, its `gcc` will generate Linux executables. Running them through WSL will of course work, but if you try to run them in plain Windows will have Windows shrug its shoulders at you.

If you want to compile Windows executables from Linux you need to use `gcc` multi-targetting, essentially using the Windows `gcc` version compiled under Linux.

The problem has nothing to do with 16-bit code, that's just Windows' best guess at the weird executable you give it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that the file formats for executables are different in Linux and Windows, so you can't take something you build n Linux (i.e. in WSL), and run it on Windows.

There's all kinds of OS-specific things to the executable file format that makes them incompatible, even before you get to interacting with the OS and the compiler's stdlib.